# GWT-Jackson-APT fails on $wnd.window JSON web-worker code for encoding strings

Tags: gwt, web-worker, gwt-jackson-apt

Finally having gotten **GWT-Jackson-APT** processors working and properly generating code for my classes, the one remaining hiccup I have is that for some reason gwt-jackson-apt uses the window **JSON** stringify (& parse) function.

```
$wnd.window.JSON.stringify(STRING)
```

The problem is that due to this being on a web-worker, $wnd.window is not defined. Even though ***JSON.stringify()*** is available in web-worker, the result is that the  code won't run correctly, even though if I modify it to be just ***JSON.stringify()*** before uploading it works pefectly.

Is there a clean way to redefine which of these functions gets used in this instance?

What is the best means of going about fixing this so that my web-worker code doesn't try to call the functions that are not available in their context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library right now uses the elemental2 version of JSON `Global.JSON.stringify`

and if we look at the implementation of the JSON in the Global class we will find that it is assigned to the window instance here :

```
@JsType(isNative = true, name = "window", namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL)
public class Global {
  public static JSONType JSON;
}
```

when this is used as `Global.JSON.stringify(someJsonObject)` from GWT java code when compile it will produce `$wnd.window.JSON.stringify(someJsonObject)` or something very similar.

in order to fix this we need to access the native JSON in a different way that does not link it the current window instance.

one solution to this is to use JsInterop to interface directly with the JSON, something like this

```
@JsType(isNative = true, namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL)
public class JSON {
    public native static String stringify(Object jsonObj);
}
```

with this implementation we can use the JSON without the window prefix and when we use it in java like this `JSON.stringify(someJsonObject)` and notice how we no longer use the one from `Global` we end up with a generated Js that looks like this `$wnd.JSON.stringify(someJsonObject)`

i run a small test and implemented this JSON in the jackson-apt lib and switched to use the new implementation instead of using `Global.JSON` and all tests passed.

to me this looks like a good issue to be reported on the project repository. and i will apply the fix ASAP.

Comment: Issue filed, thanks for digging into this Ahmad https://github.com/google/jsinterop-generator/issues/18

Comment: @dynamphorous a fix have been applied on gwt-jackson-apt, this will be a workaround until the issue in Colin comment is resolved.